# The type 'Exception' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced in ASP.NET 5 RC1

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, dnx

This issue is very easy to reproduce, but I'm not sure of the fix. I'm on Windows 10, Visual Studio 2015.  I've installed the RC1 of ASP.NET 5.

To reproduce:

New Project -> Class Library (Package)

Edit project.json, add `EnterpriseLibrary.TransientFaultHandling` to `net451` dependencies.

```
"frameworks": {
  "net451": {
    "dependencies": {
      "EnterpriseLibrary.TransientFaultHandling": "6.0.1304"
    }
  },
  "dotnet5.4": {
    "dependencies": {
      "Microsoft.CSharp": "4.0.1-beta-23516",
      "System.Collections": "4.0.11-beta-23516",
      "System.Linq": "4.0.1-beta-23516",
      "System.Runtime": "4.0.21-beta-23516",
      "System.Threading": "4.0.11-beta-23516"
    }
  }
}
```

Make `Class1` implement `ITransientErrorDetectionStrategy`.

```
public class Class1 : ITransientErrorDetectionStrategy
{
    public Class1()
    {
    }

    public bool IsTransient(Exception ex)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Build and you get the error: `.NET Framework 4.5.1 error CS0012: The type 'Exception' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.`

I've tried adding `"System.Runtime": ""` to `net451` dependencies in `project.json` but it can't be resolved.  If I try to add a reference, "System.Runtime" doesn't exist in the list of assemblies.

I think I need to use `Class Library (Package)` as I'm referencing it from an ASP.NET 5 Web API project.

In the short term I can live without `dotnet5.4` support, as I understand the TransientFaultHandling library doesn't support it yet.

But how do I make it compile for .NET 4.x?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Class Library (Package) project type you should add dependency clearly to the C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.5.1\Facades\System.Runtime.dll

1. Navigate to your managed desktop app project in the Solution Explorer.
2. Right-click the References node and click Add Reference.
3. Click the Browse tab.
4. Click Browse….
5. Navigate to the System.Runtime.dll façade. You can generally find this in a path similar to: %ProgramFiles(x86)%\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.5\Facades\System.Runtime.dll

via [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj856306.aspx)

For asp.net MVC projects with PCL there is a similar error message. Try to replace web.config section to avoid this.

```
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5"/>
```

to

```
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5">
  <assemblies>     
    <add assembly="System.Runtime, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />   
    <add assembly="System.Core, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
  </assemblies>
</compilation>
```

[Via](http://www.lyalin.com/2014/04/25/the-type-system-object-is-defined-in-an-assembly-that-is-not-reference-mvc-pcl-issue/)

Comment: This is a class library so there isn't a web.config.

Comment: Yes, but problem is not in the class library, but in the reference to it. Try this solution.
Also, you can try to add dependency clearly to the C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5.1\Facades\System.Runtime.dll it can be a version problem.

Comment: If you follow my steps the solution contains only one project, the class library, so nothing references it and there is nothing to add a web.config to.  However adding a reference to System.Runtime in the Facades folder did get the project building.. I wonder if anyone can explain what these Facades assemblies are and why this is needed?

Comment: I found solution [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj856306.aspx), hope this will be helpful for you

Comment: Thanks Vadim, that certainly does help.  If you want to update your answer to include that link and the solution of adding the reference I can mark it as the answer.

Comment: @JamesThurley done. I'm not sure it'll be actual in release version but now there are many problems with "The type X is defined in an assembly that is not referenced".